# Start Process and wait for Exit code without freezing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, exit-code

I'm trying to port a program over that I had once made in NSIS to *C# Winforms*, and I am having an issue where when I call a process, adb.exe, the whole program locks up then just throws me the final output after a few seconds.

I realise that this may have been asked a number of times, but I still can't find the solution myself even after a lot of googling (plus I'm new at using WinForms). Below is my code:

```
public static int runAdb(string args, out string output)
{
    bAdbRunning = true;

    adbProc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    adbProc.Exited += new EventHandler(adbExitHandler);
    adbProc.Start();

    // Read all output into string output
    output = adbProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    while (bAdbRunning)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    return adbProc.ExitCode;
}

private static void adbExitHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    bAdbRunning = false;
}
```

And this is the code that calls it:

```
public static void BaseOperations(Label outputWindow, ProgressBar operationsBar, int opIndex)
{
    // Run server
    if (opIndex == 0)
    {
        outputLine(outputWindow, "Shutting down existing adb server");
        runAdb("kill-server", out outText);
        operationsBar.Value += 1; // 1%

        outputLine(outputWindow, "Restarting adb server...");
        runAdb("start-server", out outText);
        operationsBar.Value += 1; // 2%;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can achieve this by listening to `Exited` event of the process.

Comment: The `Process.WaitForExit` method will block the calling thread until the process in question has exited. In this case you are blocking the main thread and consequently causing the UI to freeze. Use the `Exited` event as described by Sudhakar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Subscribe to the Process `Exited` event to achieve this.

Try This:

```
public static int runAdb(string args, out string output)
{
    adbProc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    adbProc.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExitHandler);
    adbProc.Start();

    // Read all output into string output
    output = adbProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();        
}

private void ProcessExitHandler(object sender,EventArgs args)
{

//Your process exited and now do whatever you want.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I have tried what you mentioned, in hopes that it would work, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Start-Server takes some time to work, and during that time, my GUI just locks up, the same as before. I've updated my code above to reflect changes